# MongoDB filter after populate javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm newer of nodejs, and I want to create API for my porfolio.

I have built API to get all of projects data, and I want to filter which use query after populate.

Project schema

```
const ProjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  tags: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "tag",
    },
  ],
  createAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

Tag schema

```
const TagSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  projects: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "project",
    },
  ],
  createAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});
```

if ?tags=react, rwd I wish return:

```
[ 
   {
     name: "A Project",
     description: "blablabla",
     tag: [
       { name: "react" },
       { name: "rwd" },
       { name: "antd" ),
     ]
     createdAt: "2022/2/15"
   }, 
   {
     name: "B Project",
     description: "blablabla",
     tag: [
       { name: "react" },
       { name: "rwd" },
       { name: "mui" ),
     ]
     createdAt: "2022/2/15"
   },     
]
```

this is my code below:

```
// ?tags=react, rwd
const tags = req.query.tags.split(",");
const data = await Project.find()
      .sort({ number: -1 })
      .populate({
        path: "tags",
        select: "name -_id",
        match: { name: { $in: tags } },
      });
```

Can somebody help me to figure it out? thanks!

Comment: inside the find try if `{'tags.name':'react'}` works

Comment: try { 'tag.name': { $all: ["react", "rwd"] }}